# pyttsx error: No module named 'engine'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyttsx

when i write this code:

```
import pyttsx
engine = pyttsx.init()
engine.say('hello world ')
engine.runAndWait()
```

i get this probleme

```
File "C:/Users/youssef123/PycharmProjects/fgq/ghqsd.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyttsx
  File "C:\Users\youssef123\PycharmProjects\fgq\venv\lib\site-packages\pyttsx\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from engine import Engine
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'engine'
```

how can i fix that please

Answer (score 1):

For Python3, please install the latest version via

```
pip3 install pyttsx3
```

and in coding call

```
import pyttsx3
```